# Create Datasource Hive on Pentaho hadoop

Tags: hadoop, datasource, pentaho, hive

I try pentaho hadoop to make report designer with Hive Datasource.
I have make connection to hadoop with

```
connection url: jdbc:hive://localhost:10000  and
driver class name :org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

Then I create datasource which I pointed to Hive database to access Table inside.

And then when I make design the report and drag field of table to designer workspace there is and error message

> An unexpected error has occurred: The generated SQL-query did not execute successfully.

in the log of pentaho full error like this:

```
2011-08-11 10:24:49,957 ERROR [com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.AdhocReportContentGenerator] The generated SQL-query did not execute successfully.
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: The generated SQL-query did not execute successfully.
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.SimplePmdDataFactory.buildTableModel(SimplePmdDataFactory.java:412)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.SimplePmdDataFactory.queryData(SimplePmdDataFactory.java:491)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.PmdDataFactory.queryData(PmdDataFactory.java:99)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryData(CompoundDataFactory.java:90)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryInternal(CachingDataFactory.java:256)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryData(CachingDataFactory.java:213)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryData(CompoundDataFactory.java:99)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.ReportDataRow.createDataRow(ReportDataRow.java:97)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performQuery(DefaultFlowController.java:188)
    at com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.c.a(AdhocWizardProcessorUtil.java:79)
    at com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.g.a(InteractiveAdhocReportUtils.java:1265)
    at com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.AdhocReportContentGenerator.createContent(AdhocReportContentGenerator.java:103)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SimpleContentGenerator.createContent(SimpleContentGenerator.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.a.invoke(SourceFile:220)
    at $Proxy29.createContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doGet(GenericServlet.java:261)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doPost(GenericServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.pentaho.ui.servlet.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ParentException: 
java.sql.SQLException: Error retrieving next row
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:173)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.tablemodel.ResultSetTableModelFactory.generateDefaultTableModel(ResultSetTableModelFactory.java:338)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.parametrizeAndQuery(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:426)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.SimplePmdDataFactory$PmdSQLDataFactory.parametrizeAndQuery(SimplePmdDataFactory.java:81)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.SimplePmdDataFactory.buildTableModel(SimplePmdDataFactory.java:397)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.SimplePmdDataFactory.queryData(SimplePmdDataFactory.java:491)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.PmdDataFactory.queryData(PmdDataFactory.java:99)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryData(CompoundDataFactory.java:90)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryInternal(CachingDataFactory.java:256)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryData(CachingDataFactory.java:213)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryData(CompoundDataFactory.java:99)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.ReportDataRow.createDataRow(ReportDataRow.java:97)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performQuery(DefaultFlowController.java:188)
    at com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.c.a(AdhocWizardProcessorUtil.java:79)
    at com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.g.a(InteractiveAdhocReportUtils.java:1265)
    at com.pentaho.iadhoc.service.AdhocReportContentGenerator.createContent(AdhocReportContentGenerator.java:103)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SimpleContentGenerator.createContent(SimpleContentGenerator.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.a.invoke(SourceFile:220)
    at $Proxy29.createContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doGet(GenericServlet.java:261)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doPost(GenericServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.pentaho.ui.servlet.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong with my Hive or Pentaho configuration?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to be able to use Hive tables in Pentaho BI Server (you didn't specify which tool you are using):

1. Open Pentaho Metadata Editor
2. Add new connection to generic JDBC database (configure it as you did)
3. Add some tables from Hive
4. Create new Business Model and add some tables there
5. Create new Business View and add some previously added tables.
6. Publish this configuration to BI server.
7. When creating new model, you'll see new datasource - after selecting this, you'll see your tables

Some useful links I followed to reach this solution:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc1x/07.+Importing+and+Exporting+Domains

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?83490-Pentaho-with-hive-datasource-FAILED&highlight=hive

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?80080-Cannot-create-Hive-data-source-from-User-Console&highlight=hive

I'm using Hadoop version CDH3u1 and Pentaho CE 3.8.